# Has anyone tried the ElectricBikeWheel 350 w internal battery product?

Tags: electric-bike

Looking for a Bare Bones ebike conversion system. I'm very interested in the electric bike wheel 20 inch 350 w front hub motor that is completely self-contained. It seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not looking for super performance I really just want to extend my riding time. The ease of installation of this product is amazing and the price at around $500 including a battery makes it seem almost too good to be true. I'm actually considering it's companion model which has an external battery and the front wheel hub is much smaller because the battery is not inside. It looks much less obtrusive on the front of your bike then the internal battery model. I'm guessing continued centrifugal force on the internal battery would not be a good thing either plus I can replace a external battery much easier. I've investigated other more expensive products and I just don't think I need all that they are offering . Just wondering if anybody has had experience with this product?

---

So sorry here, I posted the name of this bike wheel incorrectly. It is called a smart bike wheel. It is made in China but it's a very intriguing concept. Gyroscope and tachometer are inside this wheel to predict changes in wheel speed. One model with a bigger Hub has an internal battery and the other model which I'm more interested in has an external battery.